# How to achieve AlarmApplicationManager AlarmAccessStatus as AllowedWithWakeupCapability?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, alarm, windows-10

The `AlarmApplicationManager` provides a method `RequestAccessAsync()` to request permission from the user to be set as an alarm app. This seems to generate a dialog with `Yes` and `No` buttons. If the user taps on `No`, the value returned is `Denied` and when user taps `Yes` , the value seems to be `AllowedWithoutWakeupCapability`. But [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.alarmaccessstatus) explains that it can return 4 values including `AllowedWithWakeupCapability`. How can I achieve `AllowedWithWakeupCapability` so that the device can wake up from sleep mode when alarm time is reached?

Comment: You have to [identify yourself as an alarms app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451440.aspx) via declaring the `windows.alarm` extension, and the user must have selected you as their preferred alarm app by putting you on the lock screen.